# how to solve about regex file refining program?

Tags: python, regex, csv, file-io, optparse

I want to refine my csv file.

i imported fileinput, optparse, and re modules.

and loaded a csv file, and set if an word doesn't exist, delete it.

but i received blank file.

here is my code:

```
import fileinput
import optparse
import re

parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog -d <directory>")
parser.add_option('-d', dest='directory', type='string', help='specify file path')

dname = options.directory

for line in fileinput.input(dname, inplace=1):
    if bool(re.match("\d\d\d\d",line)) == False:
        continue
```

my csv file contains like this:

```
2014,10,21....
2014,10,22....
asdfsadf
```

so i want to remove such as line 3.

what is wrong about my code?
Any help will be very appreciating.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hint: Wouldn't you need an else or some more statements in the if in the case the line look like CSV ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not writing anything to disk at any moment. If you're looking to modify the file, you should do it explicitly. You should find some pointers on how to hand Files [in the official doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write).

Comment: Oops. i forget to write!!

Answer (score 0):

I never used fileinput and optparse library, but as for the solution, here is what I'm going to do if I'm in your position.

```
import re
CSVFile = open("FILENAME.csv", "r")
CSVFile = CSVFile.read()  <-- forgot this before.
CSVFile = CSVFile.split("\n")
RM = re.compile("\d+")
Result = ""
for Row in CSVFile:
    for Col in Row.split(","):
        # Add it to the result if it is number
        if RM.match(Col):
            Result += Col+","
        # Remove the data
        else:
            pass
CSVFile.write(Result)
CSVFile.close()
```

For more information about the regex library, refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Sorry. but split() is making AttributeError.